# Form template: PHP line in <script> cause Warning: Cannot modify header. Possible solution

Tags: php

I've few lines of script in the head of a file mixed with php:

```
    <script>$( "#company" ).autocomplete({
        source: "<?php echo  $absolute_site . "autocomplete/autocompletecompany.php" ?>"....
.............
<script>
```

Later in the file a pass a php command:

```
 header("Location: index.php?act=edit&peopleID=$last_peopleID")
```

but I get

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent

and the warning refers to the php line in the script.

How to do this without get the warning? Thanks!

**EDIT**
After reading the [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php) question (and answers) and Okneloper answer to my original question, I modified the title and I propose the solution I've used, in the hope this question is not a duplicate anymore and it could be useful to someone else who has incurred in the same problem.

**SOLUTION**

My form file included: the php part

```
 if (isset ($_POST["submit"]) ){ 
           .... all the sql commands including the:
           header("Location:pathtopage")
}
```

and the html form presentation:

```
<form> ...my form </form>
```

Problem was because the template file was calling the form file in in the body, meaning after the headers. To avoid this, in the form file, I put all the form output in a function.

```
 function output_form(){
  <form> ...my form </form>      
 }
```

In the template file, as first line I included the form file. Then later in the body (where I want print my form) I called the form output function.

```
<?php include ('formfile.php'); /* no spaces before <!!!! */ ?>
```

Later in the body

```
<?php form_output(); ?>
```

Hope this can help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Comment: @Ben Pearl Thanks for the link. I've edited my question, I suppose it's not a duplicate anymore, because I propose a solution to a more specific problem. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either send headers before you do any output or enable output buffering in the top of the script:

```
ob_start();
```

Headers are sent before the body of the response, so if you have started output of body, headers cannot be changed or added.

Comment: @ Okneloper I just added `ob_start();` as soon as I opened my first <?php and it worked. Thanks! Here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php] Mario says it is not reliable... I will verify for white spaces. Do you think to move the <script> at the end, before closing the body, would be a good idea? Thanks

Comment: @codeispoetry while ob_start fixes your problem and I is reliable enough, guys saying that you shouldn't be outputting html before sending all headers, or the other way around - sending headers (redirecting) after you had outputted some html. Concider adopting a good practice of splitting your login and presentation - so that you first have all php logic at the top of any file, including redirects, and all the HTML at the bottom of the file, or an another file.

Comment: The HTML part should only use PHP for generating output (ie. foreach loops to generate a table) and no business logic.

Comment: Very clear. Thanks. I generally try to put the php logic at the beginning (before html), but this time the form is a separate file that is include() in a template. So the page starts and in the middle include the form.php (which contains php and the html to output the form). Could you suggest a way to put the if `(isset $_POST["submit"]` before the html starts when working with templates. Or (if you know) a link to a tutorial that would show a way to do it?

Comment: If you are the author of the form.php, I suggest you split the file into 2 files, ie form-handler.php and form-template.php. Also concider using OOP. I can't recommend a particular tutorial, although Im sure there are plenty out there. I find http://www.phptherightway.com/ to be a very good overall tutorial for PHP beginners/intermediate. Athough not that thorough, covers a lot good practices and modern design patterns.

Comment: Also, consider using a templating engine like Twig (http://twig.sensiolabs.org/). Although requires some learning of stuff you think you might not need, it will teach you to split presentation from logic :)
Also it changes the way you think about templates and the flow of generating html.

Comment: Thanks! I will look at the templates you proposed. It will for sure be a good school and a learning opportunity! As you can see from my edited question, I started from your suggestion to split the form file in two files, but, instead of making two files I used a function to output my form. Now all the logic is at the beginning of the file, and the presentation comes later in the body tags. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The headers are already sent, meaning you cannot alter them.  If you want to customize the headers, you must do so before they are sent (top of the page).

If you're trying to redirect in PHP, use javascript.  This is how you do it inline:

```
function redirect($url){
    $string = '<script type="text/javascript">';
    $string .= 'window.location = "' . $url . '"';
    $string .= '</script>';
    echo $string;
}

//later in the page
redirect('example.com/my/url/here/01.');
```

Comment: "*Top of the page*" isn't very describing. More like *Before any output of any kind is made to the browser*. Also, for your solution - if I disable JavaScript on my browser, this won't work.

Comment: Thanks Tuesdave. It for sure is a good solution. I also try (as Qirel suggests) to stay as far as possible from anything that the user could disable from his browser and try to keep as much as possible server side. But yours it's a very good alternative!!